# MySQL copy value from one large table to another large table (millions of rows)

Tags: php, mysql

I have an orders table with say a million rows and a customer table with say 750k rows. All orders have a customer_id. For a certain reason, I need to add a field from the customer table onto the order table. So, I know something like this will work:

```
UPDATE orders o INNER JOIN customers c ON (o.customer_id = c.id) SET o.customer_field = c.field WHERE c.field IS NOT NULL and c.field != '';
```

However, from what I understand, doing this INNER JOIN will create a pretty massive temporary table, with all the orders matched to customers. Is that right? If so, surely that's not a great way to do this? Or will it be OK? If not, is there a better/more efficient way, maybe by paging the JOINS somehow?

Writing a script in PHP is an option but would presumably take alot longer...

Thanks

Comment: If it's once for all, do it. If you need this often, consider modifying original db structure.

Comment: Are you definitely sure that duplicating a filed is the only solution? You'll face a number of issues after you've done it. You can update in chunks by setting a loop based on order id (not customer id to prevent reading bigger tables many times).

Comment: It's once and for all @Ghigo . Thanks

Comment: @Stoleg I won't go into the details but it is necessary unfortunately. Updating in chunks is a likely option, but is it possible to somehow do that in SQL alone, or would I need to write a PHP script?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have and index on `o.customer_id`?

Comment: most probably you could just run that query directly without using steps. Assuming you have proper indexes on fields you join (customer_id, c.id) and you are not running your database server on a 386, you should be fine. You might want to dump/restore onto a test machine and try there first, but my experience is that mysql is quite efficient in such matters. Worst case, if you do need to use steps, yes, you can use a stored procedure SQL directly in mysql, so you dont need php for that.

Comment: Yes, we do have an index on customer_id on the orders. Thanks for that @TuncayGöncüoğlu . My main concern was the size of the temporary table created by the INNER JOIN, as well as if anything went wrong during the UPDATE, where would that leave us. I like the stepped approach, it just feels safer!

Comment: as you wish, however, you could just use transactions to ensure safety. start transaction, just rollback if anything goes wrong, if not, commit. This usually helps with execution speed too. Of course you need a transaction-capable engine for that, such as innodb, which is default for mysql for some time now.

Comment: Actually, good point on the transactions, thanks @TuncayGöncüoğlu . That + stepped approach = extra safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this loop. I don't have a parser at hand, but all logic is here

```
--Assuming o.ID >=1

declare @step int
declare @batch_size int
declare @max_rows int
set @step =1
set @batch_size = 100000
set @max_rows = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM orders)


LOOP

UPDATE orders o
SET o.customer_field = c.field
INNER JOIN customers c ON (o.customer_id  =c.id)   
WHERE len(c.field) >=0
AND o.id between (@step-1)*batch_size +1 and @step*batch_size

if @max_rows < @step*@batch_size 
   then 
      LEAVE LOOP
   END IF;

set @step = @step+1

END LOOP
```